# What material might by used to 'staple' coils down in this stovetop element?

Tags: heat-transfer, metals, thermal-conduction, thermal-insulation

I have the stovetop element shown in the image below. If you look at the coils, they're fixed down by what look like little staples. I'm wondering what material those staples might be. The surface they're stapled into is a bit spongey, so I assume it (the surface) is an insulator, and that therefore it doesn't really matter what material the 'staples' are.

[image][image]

Element is from a Whirlpool stovetop. Image from [this link](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Radiant-Surface-Element/WPW10342780/2117639) at repairclinic.com

Comment: Please embed the image in your post (giving credit to the owner) so that readers don't have to follow links to understand your question and so that it still makes sense if the link dies.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

I expect the same material as the coils would be the easiest answer ; nichrome  ,Inconel
( 600, 601 or other number) , chromel. There are small differences but any one you can find would be good. That would also be practical as it would be readily available to the manufacturer. Stainless like 304 will probably work but I am uncertain of the many cycles into a 1400 F ( approximately ) temperature.